# Django, filter objects and return object and object parent

Tags: python, django

I have two models**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    doc = models.CharField(max_length=45, db_index=True)

class Salary(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

In my view I need filter the  Salary and return Salary and Person to return json

```
 class SearchPersonSalary(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       doc = request.GET['doc']
       salary = Salary.objects.filter(person__doc=doc)
       data = serializers.serialize('json', salary)
       return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

> return json >>
>
> "[{"pk": 1, "model": "salary", "fields": {"year": 2014, "salary": 10121, "person": 1}}]
>
> I need person details too, example
>
> [{"pk": 1, "model": "salary", "fields": {"year": 2014, "salary": 10121, "person": {"fisrt_name":"jhon", "last_name":"huld", "doc": 2343432}}}]"

Comment: I resolved my problem
https://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers#Relations

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django's [built-in serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization) and [natural key serialization feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys):

- define a `natural_key()` method on your related model:

  ```
  class Person(models.Model):
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
      doc = models.CharField(max_length=45, db_index=True)

      def natural_key(self):
          return (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.doc)
  ```
- use `django.core.serializers.serialize()` with `use_natural_keys=True` argument:

  ```
  from django.core.serializers import serialize

  serialize('json', Salary.objects.filter(person__doc=doc), use_natural_keys=True)
  ```

Now, instead of just a foreign key to `Person`, your serialized data would contain `Person` model fields returned from `natural_key()` method.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) has a json serializer for that. Take a look [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers).